# Where can I find nut-free chocolate in the EU?

Tags: chocolate, shopping

I'm looking to make homemade chocolate bars but I'm having a hard time finding any sort of chocolate (chips or otherwise) that are nut-free.

Where can I look for these types of chocolate? Are there any companies known for selling nut-free chocolate?

Comment: Schogetten and Lindt milk chocolates don't contain nuts. Check your country specific sites that composition of products.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by 'nut-free?'  A large proportion (most?) of the chocolate sold in the UK doesn't have nuts in it but isn't guaranteed to be absolutely nut-free.  There'll be a disclaimer somewhere with words to the effect of 'produced in a factory where nuts are used.'  To all intents and purposes the chocolate is nut-free but people with severe allergies may wish to avoid that particular product.  Chocolate that is guaranteed to be nut-free is likely to be a bit more specialised.

Comment: Somewhat related, for people who have allergies: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/78927/where-can-i-buy-dark-chocolate-which-was-not-produced-in-a-factory-that-handles

Comment: People with treenut and peanut allergies sometimes can react violently to even trace amounts, so you'll see them avoid options which can be contaminated in the production process. In this case, by nut-free I mean products which do not contain the usual warnings aside from obviously not containing any nut ingredients.

Comment: So you mean 'guaranteed nut-free and no chance of cross-contamination?'  Next question, where in the EU are you\ do you intend to buy from?  It's a big place and we can give you a better answer if you can tell us what country you're in.

Comment: @BWFC For example in Poland (also EU :)) a lot of chocolates are made with hazelnut paste. And it's part of "milk chocolates" so normally you wouldn't expect the need to put hazelnut in there.

Comment: @BWFC Yes, so I'd expect them to be made somewhere that does not handle any tree nuts or peanuts in the same factory. I'd love to see some options for Portugal, but I can also buy from other countries and pay extra shipping for it. It's been hard to find so far.

Comment: @SZCZERZO KLY But I guess in that case it must be listed in the ingredients :)

Comment: @goncalotomas Yes indeed. If you are looking for chocolates made in totally nut-free factory to make chocolate bars I think it would be easier if you bought some chocolate ingredient and made it from scratch. It's much easier to buy them separately without chance of nut and you gonna melt it anyway.

Comment: What should I buy then? I can't reverse engineer the chocolate I see in the supermarket just yet :)

Comment: @goncalotomas, understood. I've found somewhere that might help, answer below.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY actually has half an idea.  There's a long list of companies started because people couldn't find the product they wanted.  You could be Portugal's first nut-free chocolate millionaire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is company in UK called [Vantage House](https://www.vantagehouse.com/chocolate-ingredients-results/INGREDIENTS-BEAN-TO-BAR-FULL-LIST) that supplies cocoa products and cocoa accessories :).

Making your own chocolate is very easy as basic one can be made with just cocoa powder, oil and sweetener (sugar, maple syrup honey anything you want).

If you like taste of some store-bought chocolate you can just use the same ingredients that are listed on the package. In EU you have % content of certain parts so it's very easy to figure out what should go in.

Answer (score 2):

[This company](https://www.nutfreechocolatepeople.com/chocolatebars.html) will send nut free chocolate worldwide.  They appear to be a small family firm that make some pretty robust claims about their nut-free credentials.  I'm not connected with them in any way and I can't vouch for how their product tastes either.  They're actually called the Nut Free Chocolate People so I'd hope they're true to their word.

Comment: I wish I could have accepted your answer and SZCZERZO KŁY's. In the end, since I wanted to make my own bars I opted for his answer, but this sounds like it will bring smiles to some special people in my life. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find anything in the shops, try online. A Google search for *chocolate sin alergenos* (without allergens -- or the accent, but that's a minor issue) from Spain gives me various shopping results on the main page: use the local language for the country you're in and I expect you'd get similar results.

Comment: Well, I've been looking and I come across some products such as chocolate drops, tablets and cookies that could be safe, but I have had a hard time finding chocolate chips (or just chocolate). I regret to say that for my language (Portuguese) your Google query does not return any useful results. Perhaps it is time to look in other countries of the EU.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it specifically mentions on the packaging that something contains nuts, it isn't supposed to, at least in the EU.

That doesn't mean there can't be traces of something in it left over from a previous production batch, and many products will warn for that in the case of nuts, but that's it.

That's nothing specific to chocolate btw, the same is true for pretty much all food stuff sold packaged in the EU, it MUST have a list of ingredients.

But if you seriously need to avoid an allergen, best shop only in specialty stores where they know the product better than would a supermarket clerk or someone manning say a gas station.

Comment: I am indeed looking for options that avoid those allergens, thus I was looking to see if I could be introduced to some of those specialty shops you mention :)

Comment: @goncalotomas that'd be extremely local knowledge of small shops, many of which won't have an internet presence. If you have specific cities in mind, list those and maybe people can point you to certain addresses.

Comment: I didn't want to turn this into a local business search as that would then turn into something specific for myself. I'd like to get some online options as I feel those would better help the rest of the community as well.

Comment: @goncalotomas you really think every mom&pop candy shop worldwide is going to be on some website? Because that's what it'd take. I know the one in the town I live in doesn't even show on google maps...

Comment: Not at all, sorry if I wasn't clear. I'd like this question to be useful for other people: if I had knowledge of small shops with this kind of chocolate I would not have asked the question. By preferring companies with Internet presence I am indeed leaving out some options, but gaining convenience in return. I don't mind paying shipping if I can order it and get it to my door in a matter of days opposite to having to drive somewhere and get it. Your approach has its merit of course, but not so much for smaller villages. In my case I've run out of places to look :(